# How to display data from related tables in CGridview in yii

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I am trying to display the results using CGridView. i have two tables **Users** and **products**. **ExiProducts** is the table which maintains the many to many relation between then and let the relation name is 'myrelation'

```
public function actionSearch() {   
   if(isset($_GET['searchButton'] && $_GET['searchType']==='products') {
       $searchString=  trim(strip_tags($_GET['searchValue']));
       $model=new Products;
       $criteria->compare('productName', $searchString, TRUE, 'AND', TRUE);
       $criteria->compare('productType',$searchString,true,'OR',TRUE);
       $criteria->compare('productBrand',$searchString,true,'OR',TRUE);
       $criteria->compare('description',$searchString,true,'OR',true);

       $dataProviderObj=new CActiveDataProvider($model, array(
           'criteria'=>$criteria,
       ));  


   }

   $this->render('search',array(
       'dataProviderObj'=>$dataProviderObj,
        'model'=>$model,

   ));

}
```

This is my **view.php**

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'users-grid',

        'dataProvider'=>$dataProviderObj,
        'columns'=>array(

            'productName',
            'productType',
            'productBrand',
            'description',
                    'I WANT THE NAME OF EVERY USER THAT CREATED THIS PRODUCT 
 HERE WHICH IS IN THE USERS TABLE '

        ),
 ));
```

Can somebody please tell me how i can get the name of the users creating those products there.
columns in **users** table are

```
UserId,
Username
```

and **ExiProducts** are

```
UserId,
ProductId
```

**Updated my code**

```
public function gridCreateUser($data,$row) {
     $myproducts=array();

     $user = $data->userId;
     $records= Users::model()->with('usersproducts')->findAll('userId=:userId',array(':userId'=>$user));
        foreach($records as $record)
        {
            foreach($record->usersproducts as $productis)
            {
                $myproducts[]=$productis->productName;
            }

        }
        return $myproducts;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

view of grid view

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'users-grid',

    'dataProvider'=>$dataProviderObj,
    'columns'=>array(

        'productName',
        'productType',
        'productBrand',
        'description',
        array(
            'name' => '<column_name>'
            'value' => array($this,'gridCreateduser')
        )
     ),
));
```

This is you grid view `value => array($this,'gridCreatedUser')` this means that grid view will search a function in its controller for a function **gridCreateUser()**

Now in controller

```
public function gridCreateUser($data,$row){

     $user = $data-><colmn_name>;
     //do your stuff for finding the username or name with $user
     //for eg.
     $detail = User::model()->findByPk($user);
     // make sure what ever model you are calling is accessible from this controller other wise you have to import the model on top of the controller above class of the controller.
     return $detail->username;
}
```

No this will send the desired value of that coulmn name to grid view.

Or you can use in a simple manner by defining relation between models inside model whose gridview you are creating

```
public function relations(){
    return array(
        'users' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Users', '<column_name>'),
    );
}
```

Then you can directly access it in you grid view

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
   'id'=>'users-grid',

   'dataProvider'=>$dataProviderObj,
   'columns'=>array(
       'productName',
       'productType',
       'productBrand',
       'description',
       array(
          'name' => '<column_name>'
          'value' => $data->users->username
       )
    ),
));
```

Comment: Your answer helped a lot sir, but the problem is my function is returning an array of values. how can i display all the values in the array there?

Comment: do you need all the values of that array? or a particular value?

Comment: yes sir, i need all the values in the array separated by comma here

Comment: i have updated the code sir, please dnt get confused by name. The names used here are exactly what i am using

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42199/discussion-between-neeraj-kumar-and-ajeet-manral)

Answer (score 1):

It is easy .

All you have to do is to write a relation in the model file ExiProducts

```
  public function relations() {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'users', 'UserId'),
        );
    }
```

And you can use this in Grid view as

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'users-grid',

    'dataProvider'=>$dataProviderObj,
'columns'=>array(

        'productName',
        'productType',
        'productBrand',
        array(
    'header'=>'User Name', 
    'value'=>'CHtml::encode($data->user->Username)',//This will use the relationship and get all the details of the paticular user from users table
        ),

    ),
));
```

Comment: You can just use user.UserName in columns definition if you have created the relation.

Answer (score 1):

Add relation in your users table by editing the relations() in your model page as shown

```
public function relations() {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'users', 'UserId'),
    );
}
```

In your view.php ,

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'users-grid',

    'dataProvider'=>$dataProviderObj,
    'columns'=>array(

        'productName',
        'productType',
        'productBrand',
        'description',
         array(
            'name'=>'User Name', 
            'value'=>$model->->user->Username,

        ),       

    ),
));
```