# Yii get Model relation in CGridView

Tags: yii

i have grid view like this

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'ingredient-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        //'id',
        'barcode',
        'ingredient',
        'pantry',
        'catid',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

i want to print last relation of my model

```
  return array(
        'cat' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Categories', 'catid'),
        'memberingredients' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Memberingredients', 'ingredient_id'),
        'recipeingredients' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Recipeingredients', 'ingredient_id'),
        'ingredientmeasurement'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'IngredientMeasurement','ing_id'),
    );
```

how i print last relation of ingredientmeasurement in grid view , Note relation contain HAS_MANY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this and you are good to go:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'ingredient-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        //'id',
        'barcode',
        'ingredient',
        'pantry',
        'catid',
        array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'html',
            'value' => function($data) {
        $countRecipe = 0;
        $findMeasures = IngredientMeasurement::model()->findAllbyAttributes(array('ing_id' => $data->id));
        $myString = '';
        foreach ($findMeasures as $ms)
        $myString.=$value->name . ',';                
        $myString.=$value->relation->col(if need next relation) . ',';
        echo $myString;
    }
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is one to one relation between the two tables then first of all change  this

```
'ingredientmeasurement'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'IngredientMeasurement','ing_id'),
```

to

```
'ingredientmeasurement'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'IngredientMeasurement','ing_id'),
```

And then you can add the following line in your **CGridView**

```
'columns'=>array(
        'ingredientmeasurement.columnName',
        'barcode',
        'ingredient',
```

Else if its Has many relation then this link might provide you the answer

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20285509/how-to-display-data-from-related-tables-in-cgridview-in-yii)